# How to tristate output digital pin on a pic 16 series microcontroller?

Tags: pic, c, output, xc8, tri-state

I know that I can set digital output pins as high and low like this in c:

```
OUTPUT_PIN = 1;
OUTPUT_PIN = 0;
```

Is there any way to set that said pin as tristate or high impedance output, as some external chips (I'll be using sram chip) require tristated/high impedance inputs to them?

I'm using xc8 c compiler.

Comment: Yes, set it as an input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 29 of the Microchip 41213D.pdf document has figure 6-1:
[image]

The D FF labelled (TRIS LATCH) means that is the TRS-state latch.  It controls (Gates) the signals from the data latch to turn off the P AND N transistors.  The input to the TRSI Latch is the W Reg.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to deal with pins that need to act as tri-state is to change the pin configuration register to so that the pin switches from being an output to being an input.

On some microcontrollers the pin configuration may be done via a register called a data direction register. On others it may be called a pin mode register.